# Values are unique? (python)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, xlrd

I used xlrd to import a table from an xlsx file. I have a method that processes the big table (named "flow") and extract a set of destinations as follows:

```
dest = []
for i in range(1, len(flow)):
    if flow[i][7] not in dest:
        dest.append(flow[i][7])
```

However, when I printed out `dest`, it gives me something like:

```
[number:6080.0, number:6080.0, number:6080.0, number:6080.0, ...]
```

which is not what I expected. I expected it to be something like `[6080, 6027, 6030]` for example.

Any ideas?

Comment: This doesn't necessarily solve your problem, but I have a suggestion. When you want to represent a set of data, use a [set](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) instead of a list.

Comment: I printed set(dest) and it gave me the same output

Comment: Is what you printed above exactly what appears when you print? Are the brackets the same? Did you leave out any quote marks? Is "number:" really what appeared, or is that a placeholder for a series of digits you didn't feel like retyping?

Comment: "number:" really appeared in the output. Brackets are the same. I did not leave out any quotation marks. The "..." in the end just means that there are more elements in the list. I wouldn't list all of them here since there are 10000 elements.

Comment: it looks like you are appending the raw output from xlrd, try something like flow[i][7].value